# Semicontinuity applied on line bundles on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth complex projective curve. Let us denote its canonical bundle by $K_C$. Let $W^1_d(C): =\{L \in \text{Pic}^d(C)| h^0(L) \geq 2\}$ be the Brill-Noether locus of degree $d$ line bundles on $C$ having atleast $2$ sections. Let $\mathcal L \in W^1_d(C)$ be such that we have $h^0((\mathcal L^*)^2 \otimes K_C)=0$. Then I have come across statements like : there exists an irreducible component $W \subset W^1_d(C)$ whose general member also satisfies $h^0((L^*)^2 \otimes K_C)=0$.

Let us start with an irreducible component of $W$ of $W^1_d(C)$. Since we have to produce an open subset of $W$ containing $\mathcal L$, in many places 'semicontinuity' is used.

Could someone describe (rigorously) how exactly semicontinuity gives rise to an open dense subset of $W$?

Is it because, if we define the map: $f: W \to \mathbb Z$ given by $L \to h^0((L^*)^2 \otimes K_C)$, then $W_n:=\{L \in W| h^0((L^*)^2 \otimes K_C) \geq n \}$ is closed in $W$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$ and hence $f$ is upper semicontinuous?

Is it obvious that $W_n$ is closed in $W$? (is it the same reason as why Brill-Noether locus are closed?) If not, then do we need to use Hartshorne Theorem $12.8$ on semicontinuity?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint: semicontinuity tells you that for any coherent sheaf $M$ on $C \times W_1^d$, flat on $W^1_d$, $t \in W^1_d \longmapsto h^i(C,M_t)$ is upper semicontinuous (ie the “strict sublevel” sets are open). In particular, the set of zeroes is open. Now take $M$ as the tensor square of the dual of the universal line bundle, tensored with the pull-back of $K_C$ (or use duality to reduce to a statement about $h^1$ without need for dualizing or involving $K_C$).

Comment: @Aphelli, thanks for the answer. I guess $M_t := M|_{C \times \{t\}}$. Do you mean pullback of $K_C$ under first projection? and for the universal line bundle $U|_{C \times \{t\}}$ recovers all line bundles of the Brill-Noether loci and thats why we have the statement right?  Question :(1) Does such Universal sheaf always exist? (i.e. for any smooth curve?) (2) Instead of $(L^*)^2 \otimes K_C$, this game can also be played with other forms right? (e.g. $L^* \otimes L_1$ for some fixed line bundle $L_1$ right?

Comment: Yes, that’s the definition for $M_t$. We indeed need to pullback $K_C$ by the first projection, and yes, the $U_{|C \times \{t\}}$ should uniquely cover all line bundles – which is why we should have the statement. As to your questions – I’d have said ‘yes’ and ‘yes’, but, while I believe that the above covers the big picture, I’m not so sure about the details any more (because my background is from scheme theory and also rather imprecise even there). However, I still believe that (2) is ‘yes’ (if the details work out and flatness holds and…).

Comment: @Aphelli, for the first question I think for moduli space of degree $d$ line bundles over curves universal bundle always exists. For the second question what details are there, Isn't that a straightforward situation as the $K_C$ case? Please let me know what other aspects you have in mind.

Comment: I think it’s straightforward as well (if the canonical bundle exists), as long as you keep working with vector bundles (so as to preserve flatness).